# Avoiding platform-dependent dependencies when creating Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

We are developing an Eclipse plugin for graphic editing of task graphs and then stores the serialized version in XML. We have used EMF and GMF to build our plugin, and were able to package and test it on win32 systems.

However, when we try to use install on other systems (64-bit windows, Linux), we get the

```
requires 'org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86[1.1.200.v20100505-1235]'
```

error.

We are not explicitly calling a win32 filesystem method, and I thought that although the plugin was developed on a win32 system, the plugin's dependency would only be on the `org.eclipse.core.filesystem` package, which would be resolved locally at install time on the user's machine.

Am I missing something? Should I edit a specific (autogenerated) file and remove the reference to the win32 package mention?

Thanks in advance for your time.

-A

Answer (score 0):

org.eclipse.core.filesystem is the plugin and org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86 is a fragment. Ideally you should have dependency on the plugin only. How did the fragment end up as a dependency in your plugin? You can safely remove the fragment from your dependency